# Escape & character in groovy script while using curl

Tags: linux, bash, shell, groovy

I'm using bash execution of curl in groovy script:

```
   descr = """
    curl --silent -k -u test:test "https://bitbucket/rest/api/1.0/projects/test/repos/test/pull-requests?state=all&at=refs/heads/release/test" | /usr/bin/core_perl/json_pp
    """
    def descrtxt = ['bash', '-c', descr].execute()
    descrtxt.waitFor()
```

Problem is curl ignoring & symbol in request.And instead of give me only request with test refs,give me all pr. 
I try to escape it with '&' and \& but no luck

Comment: Prefixing with `\\` or using single quotes around the url should do?

Comment: cfrick unfortunatelly no

Comment: Sorry, the comment ate one \ - i meant \\ - double backslash

Comment: cfrick - groovy script hung. If i run command in bash console, got an error - Invalid character found in the request target. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986

Comment: Then \\&amp; maybe? Are you sure the error is with the & and not with the / inside at?

Comment: I have the same error. I have a string with all kind of control chars on it: double quotes, single, colons, ampersands, percentage... I found a solution making the ampersand being recognized as long as no single quotes are within the fields, but no luck whatsoever when all f them are combines. Best thing I could do was double escaping empersand but the double backlash will appear in the json doc so it is not great. If I add a single backslash it actually send it with the single backslash to curl but then the internal parser complains about a malformed json doc

Comment: For the records, Im still testing but the main issue is as stated the combination of control chars in the string to be sent via curl as JSON. This is the way combinations of tricky chars have t be escaped: .replaceAll("&", "\\&").replaceAll("'", "\\'\\\\'\\'")

Answer (score 0):

use `'''` for the bash command and double in the curl command

```
descr = '''
    curl --silent -k -u test:test "https://bitbucket/rest/api/1.0/projects/test/repos/test/pull-requests?state=all&at=refs/heads/release/test" | /usr/bin/core_perl/json_pp
    '''
    def descrtxt = ['bash', '-c', descr].execute()
    descrtxt.waitFor()
```

Comment: already tried this.Nope, this not work